# Right align two buttons side by side?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want the both buttons to be snug to the right. The bottom works perfectly. However, if i add a long text to the button, for some reason it increases the width by 40px (hover over it) and theres space on the right side. How do i make the text snug to the right like the bottom?:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/pNGrpcgD1z

Comment: `text-base` and `text-xl` are both for setting text size, so you have to use only one.

Answer (score 1):

The gap comes from the fact the element tries to be as wide as it can, but there is still not enough space for the last word, so it wraps to a new line, but the width is kept. You could consider forcing no text wrapping to occur by applying `white-space: nowrap` via the `whitespace-no-wrap` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="fixed z-20 w-[448px] rounded-t-lg rounded-br-lg bg-blue-500 py-3.5 pl-4 pr-8 text-base text-xl text-white shadow-lg md:bottom-10 md:left-10">
    <div class="right-0 ml-auto mt-3 flex w-full gap-8 font-semibold uppercase">
        <button type="button" class="ml-auto font-semibold uppercase">Dismiss</button>
        <div role="button" tabindex="0">
            <div class="h-full"><a id="btnLink-lfru" target="_self" href="/certifications/cpma" class="none whitespace-nowrap">Go back to the previous page</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```